# Mysql query to get addresses

Tags: mysql

I have table contacts with below data

```
id | primary_address_street | alt_address_street

1  | 300,Main Street        | 300,Main Street
2  | 46,Glen Rd             | NULL 
3  | 33 St George's Road    | 33 St George's Road
4  | 33 St George's Road    | 39 St Martins Road 
5  | 37 St Martins Road     | 300,Main Street
```

I need below output i.e I need both streets as a single column but if primary_address_street is equal to alt_street_address then I need only one of its values Eg : In id 1 & 3 both the columns have same values and in that case I need that entry only once

```
aid |  address    
1 | 300,Main Street
2 | 46,Glen Rd
3 | 33 St George's Road
4 | 33 St George's Road
4 | 39 St Martins Road
5 | 37 St Martins Road     
5 | 300,Main Street
```

Currently my sql query is as below

```
select primary_address_street as address from contacts
UNION ALL
select alt_address_street as address from contacts
```

How do I achieve this result?

Comment: Removing the `ALL` keyword will make the union _distinct_ which would remove duplicates.  Your query doesn't select the `id` column, however, so I'm not sure what, exactly, qualifies as a "duplicate".

Comment: Duplicate here will only be there if both primary and alternate address fields values are same in a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a predicate on one of the queries, to omit rows where alt_address matches primary_address_street.

For example, append something like this to the end of your query:

```
 WHERE NOT ( alt_address_street <=> primary_address_street )
```

appending that to your existing query gives:

```
select primary_address_street as address from contacts
UNION ALL
select alt_address_street as address from contacts
    WHERE NOT ( alt_address_street <=> primary_address_street )
```

The first select returns all rows, the second select returns only rows that have a different alt_address_street. That uses the MySQL-specific NULL-safe comparison operator. Depending on how you want to handle NULL values, you could use a simple inequality comparison instead, e.g.

```
    WHERE alt_address_street <> primary_address_street
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT primary_address_street AS address FROM contacts
    UNION ALL
SELECT alt_address_street AS contacts FROM table WHERE primary_address_street <> alt_address_street
```

I think this does what you want.

If you want to keep the `id` column, which is what you're showing in your desired results but not in your query, then it's easier:

```
SELECT id AS aid, primary_address_street AS address FROM contacts
    UNION 
SELECT id AS aid, alt_address_street AS address FROM contacts
    WHERE alt_address_street IS NOT NULL
```

This is essentially what you already have, but including the `id`, and removing the `ALL` keyword. That means duplicates will be removed; and once the `id` is in there, duplicates will only turn up if the two address fields are the same. I've also added something to remove the `NULL`s that will otherwise turn up.